# How to add constraints in fmincon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use `fmincon` and I have problem with the constraints. My constraints change in the case of input and in one case I have 9 and in another case I have 18 constraints. The way that I define my constraint is like below:

```
if Input(1+(i-1)*3600*Tpred/Nu/60,3) == 0
  %Tamb
  ineq1(i,1)=(-y1(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,2)=(-y2(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,3)=(-y3(i,1)+16);
  %Tamb+1     
  ineq1(i,4)=(-y12(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,5)=(-y22(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,6)=(-y32(i,1)+16);
  %Tamb-1     
  ineq1(i,7)=(-y13(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,8)=(-y23(i,1)+16);
  ineq1(i,9)=(-y33(i,1)+16);
else
  %Tamb
  ineq1(i,1)=(y1(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,2)=(-y1(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,1)=(y1(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,3)=(y2(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,4)=(-y2(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,2)=(y2(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,5)=(y3(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,6)=(-y3(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,3)=(y3(i,1)-23)^2;
  %Tamb+1
  ineq1(i,7)=(y12(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,8)=(-y12(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,4)=(y12(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,9)=(y22(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,10)=(-y22(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,5)=(y22(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,11)=(y32(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,12)=(-y32(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,6)=(y32(i,1)-23)^2;
  %Tamb-1
  ineq1(i,13)=(y13(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,14)=(-y13(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,7)=(y13(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,15)=(y23(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,16)=(-y23(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,8)=(y23(i,1)-23)^2;

  ineq1(i,17)=(y33(i,1)-25);
  ineq1(i,18)=(-y33(i,1)+21);
  eq1(i,9)=(y33(i,1)-23)^2;
end
```

I run it step by step and it goes in if-condition and calculate constraints in both cases. But I don't know why my `fmincon` can't satisfy the constraints. I know my model can satisfy them if inputs change but `fmincon` without any error on waning just can't satisfy them. Also as I check my inequality constraints are positive which must me negative.

Am I define my constraints wrong?

With best regards,

Comment: It sure would help if your code would contain the call to `fmincon`. Also it's impossible to know if it's correct unless you tell us what the constraints should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the minimization process fmincon assumes that the size of the constraints vector doesn't change. This is because in order to do the minimization it has to compute the gradient of the cost function, as well as the gradient of the constraints, and it can't see some of the elements disappear from one function call to another.

Maybe a possibility could be to redefine your problem with a constraints vector always set to the maximum size (in your case 18), and set to -1 the latest components when only half are needed. However, notice that with this solution you will loose some of the regularity of the problem.